# Google column chart y axis start reverse

Tags: laravel, charts, google-visualization, eloquent

As you see in picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ihC.jpg column that has 0 data is higher than column with value of 1 and 2. And y axis starting reverse, 0 is on the top instead on bottom. This happened when I use laravel eloquent.

Here is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  <div class="container">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['User', 'Added'],

          @if ($users)

            @foreach ($users as $user)

              ['{{$user->name}}', '{{$user->members->count()}}'],

            @endforeach

          @endif

        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Users',
          },
          vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal',
          },

        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>

    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 'auto'; height: 500px;"></div>

  </div>

@endsection
```

I tried to add this:

```
vAxis: { minValue: 0 },
```

and this:

```
vAxis: { direction: -1, },
```

but nothing helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the values for the y-axis are strings instead of numbers...

remove the single quotes from the second array value...

change --> `['{{$user->name}}', '{{$user->members->count()}}'],`

to --> `['{{$user->name}}', {{$user->members->count()}}],`

Comment: I mark it now. Sorry I did't do it before, I did not know about it ;)